# Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to Complex Type

Tags: c#, json, casting, json.net

I have json as follows,

```
{
  "H": "Macellum",
  "M": "Receive",
  "A": [
    {
      "CustomerId": "172600",
      "OrderId": "69931",
      "OrderStatus": "E0",
      "Buy": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

and complex type

```
public class OrderStats
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string Buy { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying a casting as follows,

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(message);
OrderStats info = (OrderStats)obj.A[0]; //exception
OrderStats info = obj.A[0] as OrderStats; //info is null
```

But error as follows

> Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to OrderStatus

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about this one?

```
var str = "YOUR_JSON_HERE";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(str);
OrderStats info = ((JArray)obj.A)[0].ToObject<OrderStats>();
```

Comment: Please pay attention that there is missing comma at the end of `"M": "Receive"`

Comment: I can not change the class structure

Comment: Don't you have a compilation error: `'OrderStatus': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type`?

Comment: I am sorry for typo again, class name is OrderStats

Comment: I have fixed answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152067/discussion-between-viktor-oleksyshyn-and-ibubi).

Comment: Solution if you don't have an array: `((JObject)Tags).ToObject<OrderStats>();`

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution a bit trivial like this,

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(message);
OrderStats info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderStats>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj.A[0]));
```

Comment: Because your error come from `Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to Complex Type` but your post is `Conver from JSON string to Complex Type`. So that @viktor's solution is correct for string convert, and your solution here is correct for Linq.JObject convert.

Answer (score 0):

i`m reviewing this solutions, but i think it's not necessary to use dynamic key,

i did this and it's work for me:

OrderStats info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str)

It's simplified that other lines that you mention, but thanks for the advice, it was

correct for me

Answer (score 0):

```
string jsonString = "{\"name\": \"John Doe\", \"age\": 30, \"email\": \"johndoe@example.com\"}";

// Parse the JSON string into a JObject
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

// Convert the JObject into a complex type object
var person = jsonObject.ToObject<Person>();
```